# Save date from DatePicker to SQlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-fragments, datetimepicker

I have created a variable of type Date in Entity.
And I have created a Fragment DatePicker and return a Date value to MainActivity as String, but my database needs a Date type variable. How do I get a Date with a Date type? or a better method

I also have a TypeConverter.
I will use the Date to sort the timeline.

DatePickerFragment

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mont = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), DatePickerFragment.this, year, mont, day);
}


@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    Date selectedDate = Date.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(c.getTime()));


    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(
            getTargetRequestCode(), 1,
            new Intent().putExtra("selectedDate", selectedDate)
    );


}
```

This is received class

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

DialogFragment datePicker;


EditText departureEdt;

String selectedDate;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final FragmentManager fm = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transportation_fragment, container, false);

    departureEdt = view.findViewById(R.id.departure_date);
    departureEdt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker.setTargetFragment(TransportationFragment.this, 1);
            datePicker.show(fm, "datePicker");

        }
    });


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // get date from string
        selectedDate = data.getStringExtra("selectedDate");

        // set the value of the editText
        departureEdt.setText(selectedDate);

    }
}
```